# Can't get NodeJS to write anything to a writable stream

Tags: node.js

Running NodeJS (`v8.16.2`) locally on the command line. I scrape an e-commerce website, gather the relevant information into a data-structure, then try to write it into a plain-text CSV file (my records don't have a fixed set of fields) manually by creating a write stream. This last step isn't working.

```
// Other stuff

const exitHandler = function(options, exitCode) {
    if (exitCode || exitCode !== 0) console.log(exitCode);
    // Other stuff
    writeToCsv();
    if (options.exit) process.exit();
}

const writeToCsv = function() {
    let ws = fs.createWriteStream('./final-data.csv');
    const crlf = '\n\r'; // might need to reverse this

    // Please ignore the weird layout
    for (let seller in finalData.sellers) {
        ws.write('Seller:,' + seller + crlf + ',Brands:');
        for (let brand of finalData.sellers[seller].brands) {
            ws.write(',' + brand);
        }
        ws.write(crlf + ',Addresses:');
        for (let addr of finalData.sellers[seller].addrs) {
            ws.write(',"' + addr + '"');
        }
        ws.write(crlf);
    }
    ws.on('finish', () => {
        console.log('Wrote all data'); // never prints this
    });
    ws.end();
}

process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind(null,{cleanup:true}));
```

I suspect this is because NodeJS exits before the data has been flushed to disk, but can't figure out a way to make NodeJS flush the data synchronously.

**PS:** new to NodeJS

Comment: Try `async function(options, exitCode)` and `await writeToCsv();`

Comment: Add  ws.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

to check what exactly is the error?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Didn't print anything.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov didn't work...

Comment: when the process is exit then you are running your code(exitHandler). I don't think it will work like this? When finalData is computed then you should call writeToCsv function.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Node is exiting when everything has finished. Since all the pages are fetched and parsed asynchronously, couldn't find any other way of determining when `finalData` has been fully computed.

Answer (score 0):

please check out below example and integrate it
as per your comment i updated code

```
async function writeDataInCSV(filePath, dynamicHeader, data) {
    const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
      path: filePath,
      header: dynamicHeader
    });
    await csvWriter
      .writeRecords(data)
      .then(()=> console.log('The CSV file was written successfully'));
} 

writeDataInCSV('out.csv',dynamicHeader, Data)
```

here set array of header and make data and pass to writeDataInCSV method

Comment: I don't have fixed fields. I have multi-valued fields (for every seller there is a `Set` of brands and a `Set` of addresses). Haven't actually tried this code, but I've seen something similar and not sure how it would work.

Comment: so make it one method like writeDataInCSV(filePath, dynamicHeader, data)
```
async function writeDataInCSV(filePath, dynamicHeader, data) {
 const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
   path: filePath,
   header: dynamicHeader
 });
 await csvWriter
   .writeRecords(data)
   .then(()=> console.log('The CSV file was written successfully'));
}
```